# Pandas Merg and Calculation in Matrix

Tags: python, pandas

I have problems with a matrix search and calculation.
I have a df1 with different year values for each indicator and country.
I have a df2 with combinations of countries and yearly values.
The desired output is df3 where each country combination has a new column with the product of the indicator created and calculated.

I tried several things with loc and splitting but was not able to achieve it.

Df1

```
df1 =pd.DataFrame({'Country':['Armenia','Azerbaidjan','Belarus','Armenia','Azerbaidjan','Belarus'],\
             'Indictaor':['G','G','G','H', 'H', 'H'],'2005':[3,4,5,6,7,4],'2006':[6,3,1,3,5,6]})
```

Df2

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Year':[2005,2006,2005,2006],
                    'Country1':['Armenia','Armenia','Azerbaidjan','Azerbaidjan'],
                    'Country2': ['Belarus','Belarus','Belarus','Belarus']})
```

Df3

```
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'Year':[2005,2006,2005,2006],                   
                    'Country2': ['Belarus','Belarus','Belarus','Belarus'],
                    'Country1':['Armenia','Armenia','Azerbaidjan','Azerbaidjan'],
                     'IndictaorGProduct':[15,6,35,5],
                      'IndictaorHProduct':[24,18,28,30]})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like this. It is only one of many ways I think.

`df[df['col'] == hoge]` which returns match `hoge`.

Add new column with a list to dataframe.

```
G = []
H = []

for i in range(4):

    rowlist = df2.iloc[i].to_list()

    year = str(rowlist[0])
    country1 = rowlist[1]
    country2 = rowlist[2]

    # make G list
    tmp1 = df1[df1['Indictaor'] == 'G']
    row1 = tmp1[tmp1['Country'] == country1].index[0]
    tmp2 = df1[df1['Indictaor'] == 'G']
    row2 = tmp2[tmp2['Country'] == country2].index[0]
    G.append(df1[year].iloc[row1] * df1[year].iloc[row2])
    # make H list
    tmp1 = df1[df1['Indictaor'] == 'H']
    row1 = tmp1[tmp1['Country'] == country1].index[0]
    tmp2 = df1[df1['Indictaor'] == 'H']
    row2 = tmp2[tmp2['Country'] == country2].index[0]
    H.append(df1[year].iloc[row1] * df1[year].iloc[row2])


df2['IndictaorGProduct'] = G
df2['IndictaorHProduct'] = H
print(df2)
```

Comment: Thank you very much shimo for this help. I almost adapted it in my program. One problem I have is that df2 the year are in datetime format so i get an error. Any help here?

Comment: I would change each item of df2 time col,  like `d = datetime.datetime.now()`  `pd.to_datetime(d).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")`. Use pd.to_datetime() to make timestamp, and strftime to make formatted time.

Comment: Thank you. I desperately tried everythign the last 3 hours the key erro stays the same. he ca not find the specified year in the columns headings of df1.